# || usage in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am writing an easy IF condition. The function is to judge each row of the matrix to be certain vectors. The code is as follows:

```
  if (compareM(i,:)==[1, 0])||(compareM(i,:) ==[2, 1])
      match_1 = match_1 +1;
  else
      mismatch_1 = mismatch_1 +1;
  end
```

The error said ''Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values''.

compareM is a n by 2 matrix and I wonder if the error is made by || operation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing vectors, not scalar values, you have to use `|` operator. As a result you get logical vector of element-by-element pairwise comparison. To use it in IF statement you have to convert either each logical statement (then use `||`) or the result of `|` the to scalar with ALL, ANY or other function.

If you want to compare to vectors for equality use ISEQUAL function as

```
if isequal(compareM(i,:)==[1, 0]) || isequal(compareM(i,:)==[2, 1])
```

Comment: Believe this should read `if isequal(compareM(i,:), [1,0])`; right now you have a combination of the corrected version and the original.

Comment: @yuk Yes! Thank you . For vectors, it's different.

Answer (score 1):

`compareM(i, :)` evaluates to a 1x2 numeric array, so `compareM(i,:)==[1, 0]` evaluates to a 1x2 logical array. The same for the expression to the right of the `||` sign. But you need a single logical value on each side of `||`, not a 1x2 array of logical values.

If you want this expression to evaluate to true if both values on the lhs of `==` are the same as the corresponding elements on the rhs, wrap `all()` around each side:

```
all(compareM(i,:)==[1, 0]) || all(compareM(i,:) ==[2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((compareM(i,:)==[1, 0])||(compareM(i,:) ==[2, 1]))
    match_1 = match_1 +1;
else
    mismatch_1 = mismatch_1 +1;
end
```

Note the outer enclosing parentheses.